# full browser width and css dynamically positioned elements

Tags: css

I have HTML

```
<div class="Box">
    <img width=100% src="...">
</div>
<table class="tab1">
    ...
</table>
```

I want these two elements to reposition depending on the size of the screen that they are displayed on. On narrow screens such as mobile phones or low-resolution projectors I want the table to appear centered underneath the div. With the div scaled to take up the full width of the parent element. But on wide screens I want the table to appear next to the div, with the two of them taking up the full width of the parent element.

Is it possible to do this in pure CSS?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried? Also, can you provide a place, like on jsfiddle.net, where we can see what you've tried and provide feedback?

Comment: What width would you define as a "mobile or low resolution porjectors"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need responsive web design. Here's a good article on how to do it: http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design

Comment: the css "@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {" looks perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use CSS3 @media for that problem.

```
.Box
{
    width: 100%;
}


/* overwrite, if smartphone */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) 
{
    .Box, .tab1
    {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Alternative you can try media type handheld:

```
@media handheld 
{
    .Box, .tab1
    {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

found on: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp